# What encoding does :! use?

Tags: vimscript, command-line, external-command, encoding

I'd like low-level control over exactly what bytes I send and receive from a process spawned from some vimscript. What encoding is used for communications with commands started with `:!foo`? Can I influence this choice? How are newlines handled?

Comment: There is the 'termencoding' option. The help page at [:h encoding-table](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/mbyte.txt.html#encoding-table) also talks a bit about this.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Hm. None of the `:help` text about `'termencoding'` or `encoding-table` mentions anything about communications with subprocesses; why do you think that's the right option? From my tests it also doesn't seem to control the encoding used for communicating with subprocesses; from a new file, `:set encoding=latin1 fileencoding=latin1 termencoding=utf-8`, and insert a single `0xff` byte (e.g. by `<Ctrl-v>xff`). Then `:%!xxd` will show that `xxd` received an `0xff` byte, which is not the `utf-8` encoding of codepoint 255.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with subprocesses. Termencoding is what is used to convert the output from running external processes to the internal used encoding. If 'termencoding isn't set, then I think Vim assumes the external programs to execute in 'encoding' BTW: you should never set 'encoding' after startup.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt You say `'termencoding'` is used to convert output from external processes. I haven't tested that, so it may be right, and I'll try later to verify/refute. In the meantime, what encoding is used to send input to external processes? As my proposed experiment above shows, it isn't `'termencoding'`.

Comment: It's 'encoding' as said before. That is my understanding from the documentation and what my past experience shows. I have never verified it at the source level, which is the reason I am posting this as comment and not as answer.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt It seems `'termencoding'` is also not used for converting output from external processes. Starting from a fresh instance of vim, do `:set encoding=utf-8 fileencoding=utf-8 termencoding=latin1`, then insert the text `00000000: e298 8341 0a`, then do `:%!xxd -r`. If this decoded `xxd`'s output as `latin1`, the letter `A` would be in column 4; instead it is in column 2. It also doesn't appear to simply use `'encoding'` for everything, though the setup that demonstrates that is a bit more complex. I conclude that you, like me, do not know the answer.

Comment: that is not what I see. First of all, are you using a gui or the terminal? That has significant impact, so please provide complete reproducible examples. I just made a small test on Windows gui and whatever I use as 'encoding' is what get's seen by filtering the line through xxd).

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt The GUI (at least here) does not even allow me to set `'termencoding'`, so to be as generous as possible I performed these tests in a terminal (on Linux). What do you see when you perform my experiments?

Comment: same thing: in a terminal with encoding set to 'latin9' `%!xxd` returns `f6` which is the latin1 char for `ö` and in an utf-8 terminal with encoding set to `utf-8` it returns `c3b6` which is the corresponding UTF codepoint. I did not test termencoding, as I do not really have a non utf-8 locale around and I do not thing it makes a difference for filtering. Note also, that I think Vim writes temporary files before executing the commands. That might or might not interfere.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt So, you performed a different experiment and saw different results. That's not very informative, especially since you didn't even give details about what alternate experiment you performed (What did you do before running `%!xxd`? What were the other encoding settings?). What happens when you try exactly the experiment I proposed?

Comment: That is exactly the same experiement I did before. And I already said, there was simply one valid latin1 multibyte character in that file, `ö` But hey, you have the questions, I am here to help you. Won't happen again, I promise.